# mysql database recovery lying on lvm partition which is corrupted

Tags: recovery, lvm

I have a Mysql database running on a Linux RHEL7 server lying on an lvm ext4 partition which is 100% full now. The respective volume group and lvm has been extended but while running "resize2fs /dev/vg/lvm" for resizing, then showing permission denied, to resolve this issue by mistakenly I have executed lvreduce -L command and may be some data has been destroyed, I am no sure but database is not getting connected, but partition is still showing 100% full. I have also tried to take backup of all the data to another system, but backup process also got failed after completing some percentages, can anyone help me here how can I recover the data?

I have executed the e2fsck command but as this is a system partition /var, could not unmount this, then I tried to reduce some space in KB by running lvreduce -L command and resizing the ext4 partition mounted on /var

I were expecting that if some little space in KB would be reduced then the partition might have been resized.